# Odd behavior windows copy

Tags: windows-7

If I copy my `C:/Users/Michael Xu/` folder directly to a flash drive, it says it copies only 40 MB [image] 
 However if I open that directory and ctrl+a and copy that, it copies all the 2 gb. What is going on?[image]

Comment: Maybe you have existing files inside your folder. or maybe you have hidden files.

Comment: If you do the ~45MB copy and compare, what was left out?